# MySQL window function over user-defined variable

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, accumulate

Let's consider this table:

```
select * from foo;
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 8 |
+---+---+
```

If we do this:

```
select a, b, sum(b) over (order by a) as b_accum
from foo order by a ASC;
```

the result makes perfect sense: the 3rd column equals to the 2nd plus the sum of all 2nd column's rows above:

```
+---+---+---------+
| a | b | b_accum |
+---+---+---------+
| 1 | 2 |       2 |
| 4 | 5 |       7 |
| 6 | 8 |      15 |
+---+---+---------+
```

However, if we sum over user-defined variables, things get strange:

```
select a, b, @b2 := b as b2,
sum(b) over (order by a) as b_accum,
sum(@b2) over (order by a) as b2_accum
from foo order by a ASC;

+---+---+----+---------+----------+
| a | b | b2 | b_accum | b2_accum |
+---+---+----+---------+----------+
| 1 | 2 |  2 |       2 |        8 |
| 4 | 5 |  5 |       7 |       10 |
| 6 | 8 |  8 |      15 |       15 |
+---+---+----+---------+----------+
```

Why is `b_accum` not equal to `b2_accum`?

(Version 8.0.15).

Comment: That behavior likely isn't guaranteed: `https://dbfiddle.uk/WyiKNuYd` ... You might want to avoid that entirely.  What's your real purpose / intent?

Comment: @JonArmstrong In my case `b2` is calculated from other columns in some complicated manner, and I need to sum over it like in this example. Currently leaning towards using a nested query instead.

Comment: Try updating your question to contain the actual problem, with the complete test case, as I showed.  The case you posted isn't stable... and I wouldn't depend on it.  You can place expressions in a `SUM(expresssion) OVER (...)` expression.  It's hard to guess what behavior you are expecting.  Data (in a complete test case) plus expected result would help.

Comment: If you just want the standard SUM window function behavior, shown in b_accum, why not use that with your complex expression (or derived in some way, CTE term, etc)?

Comment: @JonArmstrong My approach is to get full understanding of how things work at the simplest level. If they don't behave (or I don't get how they do), I see no point in trying to get it work with real, complicated stuff. So, the question stands as asked. _If_ there is no coherent explanation how `b2_accum` is calculated, then to say "it's a bug" would be a good answer — I'll make conclusions and move on trying other approaches on my own.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html ... "The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment."  Bottom line, don't depend on this behavior.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Doing `SUM(expresssion) OVER (...)` works, but the point of using variables is to output the `expresssion` column alongside the `SUM`: it would be inefficient to calculate the expression twice.

Comment: 1) Smart engines might recognize and avoid the duplicate calculation.  2) derived column in .. CTE or derived table 3) generated column (for a very common calculation over each row)

Comment: @Greendrake: Were you able to figure out the solution? My problem is very similar to yours and would not be able to make changes to the existing query which uses user-defined variables. But if I use windows function on this user-defined variable, it doesn't work